# React Native - iOS - Local image invisible (works on android)

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm mapping TouchableOpacity with an Image nested inside of it. It works great on Android but on iOS the image is invisible. There is still a 75x75 touchable opacity that I can tap but the image is invisible in the modal that pops up and just in general.

How does this work?
I'm using Expo SDK FileSystem to get the path of each image.

For example: file://path/to/container/progress/myfilehash.jpg

I push this to my state and map it in the component. the require() function WILL NOT WORK for the way I am doing this. I think it is purely a problem with the rendering.

Map code:

```
{this.state.images.map((val, key) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    key={key}
    onPress={() => this.setState({active: val, modal: true})}
  >
    <Image
      style={{width: 75, height: 75}}
      source={{isStatic: true, uri: val}}
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>
))}
```

Modal:

```
<Container style={Colors.Backdrop}>
  <Header style={Colors.Navbar}>
    <Left>
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => {
          this.setState({modal: false})
      }}>
        <Icon
          name="arrow-back"
          style={{color: 'white'}}
        />
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </Left>
    <Body></Body>
    <Right>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
        this._deleteImage(this.state.active);
      }}>
        <Text
          style={[
            Colors.ErrorText, {
              fontSize: 24,
              marginRight: 10
            }
        ]}>&times;</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Right>
  </Header>
  <Content>
    <View
      style={{flex: 1}}
    >
      <FitImage
        source={{uri: this.state.active}}
      />
    </View>
  </Content>
</Container>
```

Code for fetching image paths. (NOTE: I tried not truncating "file://" from ios with same exact result)

```
_getAllImagesInDirectory = async() => {
    let dir = await FileSystem.readDirectoryAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'progress');

    dir.forEach((val) => {
      this.state.images.push(Platform.OS === 'ios' ? FileSystem.documentDirectory.substring(7, FileSystem.documentDirectory.length) : FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'progress/' + val);
    });

    await this.setState({images: this.state.images, loading: false});
}
```

Comment: @Luminosity, did you set the size for the picture?

Comment: Yes, in the example and description you can see I have it set to 75px by 75px.

Comment: @Luminosity, sorry missed that. I just remember that being a problem I had before. If you changed the backgroundColor of the button to red or something does it take up the space you are expecting the picture to be in?

Comment: Have you tried it with other image? Usually some pictures can't be loaded in some devices because the size. Try the same thing with other image to check if the image is not the problem

Comment: No images from the expo container work period.

Comment: Is this question still up? @thecoolestguyever123

Comment: can you provide, how are you using `_getAllImagesInDirectory `

Comment: try to add `cache: 'reload'` to Image's source prop

Comment: Where are you importing TouchableOpacity from? I had issues when it auto imported from gesture-handler rather than react-native. Just something to check.

Comment: what is react native version of your project?

Comment: Since you are using expo, an expo snack with relevant code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem once, I solved it by pasting the image in the root folder and then used that path in the source of Image tag.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the context of this question sir.